# Pandas, get max and second place from sub column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
    usersidid   clienthostid    LoginDaysSum    
0       12            1             240     
1       11            1             60  
3       5             1             5       
4       6             3             2702    
2       10            3             423     
5       8             3             18
```

each clienthostid has usersidid with LoginDaysSum.
the df is sorted

```
df.sort_values(['clienthostid', 'LoginDaysSum'], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True)
```

Now, what I need is for each clienthostid is to get his max LoginDaysSum, aka, first_place and his second_place and calculate (first_place/second_place)

for example- usersidid = 1:

```
first_place = 240
second_place = 60
(first_place/second_place) = 4
```

How the hell do I do that? I tried a few approaches but I couldn't find anything to access the different member from the same column, something like:

```
df['clienthostid'].apply(x: x.max() / x.one_index_lower_from_max())
```

Would appreciate any suggestions,

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and for each divide first and second value selected by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html) or [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
df.sort_values(['clienthostid', 'LoginDaysSum'], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True)

df = df.groupby(['clienthostid'], sort=False)['LoginDaysSum']
       .apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0] / x.iloc[1])

print (df)
clienthostid
1    4.000000
3    6.387707
Name: LoginDaysSum, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 3):

```
print(
    df.groupby('clienthostid')
      .LoginDaysSum.nlargest(2)
      .sort_values()
      .groupby(level=0)
      .pct_change().dropna().add(1)
      .reset_index(1, drop=True)
)

clienthostid
1    4.000000
3    6.387707
Name: LoginDaysSum, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative using [`Groupby.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html) to compute the top 2 maximum values per group. Divide element-wise by shifting the 2nd max element by one position to the top so that it is aligned with the 1st max.

This is done by broadcasting them across `level=1` and then taking the first item from each group grouped across `level=0`.

```
grp = df.groupby('clienthostid').LoginDaysSum
grp.nlargest(2).div(grp.shift(-1), level=1).groupby(level=0).first()

clienthostid
1    4.000000
3    6.387707
Name: LoginDaysSum, dtype: float64
```

Another equivalent variant:

```
grp = df.groupby('clienthostid').LoginDaysSum.nlargest(2)
grp.div(grp.shift(-1)).groupby(level=0).nth(0)

clienthostid
1    4.000000
3    6.387707
Name: LoginDaysSum, dtype: float64
```

---

Since *LoginDaysSum* are already sorted in descending order beforehand, calling `nlargest` seems to be a rather redundant operation here. Alternatively, `.head(2)` would actually suffice and would produce a quicker outcome too.

We then divide every value in even row index positions by their next odd index location value.

```
grp = df.groupby('clienthostid').LoginDaysSum.head(2)
pd.Series(grp.iloc[::2].values/(grp.iloc[1::2].values), df.clienthostid.unique())

1    4.000000
3    6.387707
dtype: float64
```